Error Message while testing memory leak scenarios in C under Windows?
Here is my test code:
// cl /Zi /Fe.\build\main.exe /Fo.\build\main.o .\src\main.c
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* alloc_memory(size_t capacity)
{
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity);
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    //_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW);

    printf("- Memory Leak Test [id:0003] -\n");

    int element_count = 5;
    int *arr = alloc_memory(element_count);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i*10;
    }

    printf("- Output(1) -\n");
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
    {
        printf("address of arr: %p, value of arr: %d\n", &arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
   
    printf("- Output(2) -\n");
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
    {
        printf("address of arr: %p, value of arr: %d\n", arr, *arr);
        arr++;
    }

    free(arr);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

I'm running the following in cmd:
cl /Zi /MTd /Fe.\build\main.exe /Fo.\build\main.o .\src\main.c && .\build\main.exe
The output is here:
- Memory Leak Test [id:0003] -
- Output(1) -
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA0, value of arr: 0
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA4, value of arr: 10
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA8, value of arr: 20
address of arr: 0000016700B90AAC, value of arr: 30
address of arr: 0000016700B90AB0, value of arr: 40
- Output(2) -
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA0, value of arr: 0
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA4, value of arr: 10
address of arr: 0000016700B90AA8, value of arr: 20
address of arr: 0000016700B90AAC, value of arr: 30
address of arr: 0000016700B90AB0, value of arr: 40

Once the execution is done, I'm getting the following error dialog. Could you please help me where is this coming from?


You modify arr and then try to free the modified value. You have to free the exact same pointer that was returned from malloc.

Ah! Of course, what am I doing :) Thanks.

Got a backup of the original pointer before shifting it around. That fixed the issue, now I'm only getting the memory leak dialog if I comment out the free(). It was a good test after all, catching the pointer disaster too :)
